# Is it possible to pass arguments directly when embedding a Sightly component?

Tags: aem, sightly

I have a component which has some conditional logic in it based on certain values edited by the user. To make it easier for them in some cases, I'm hoping to set one or more of those values when embedding the sub-component in another component. Something like this (though this errors out):

```
<sly data-sly-resource="${ @path='emailOptIn', resourceType='/apps/br/components/content/custom-forms/form-input' @type='checkbox'}"></sly>
```

Is that even possible? Do I have to process it via `data-sly-use` and JS or Java, even if I'm not applying any business logic? Would it be better to create a separate template, rather than shoehorning too much conditional logic into this one?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the simplest way to achieve what you want would be through a Sightly template that would render what your `/apps/br/components/content/custom-forms/form-input` component does now, with the added check (`data-sly-test`) of your `type` parameter.

```
<template data-sly-template.form-input="${@ type = 'defines the input type'}">
    <div data-sly-test="${type == 'checkbox'}">
    ...
    </div>
</template>
```

You could also process this through the Use-API. The Use-API is not built just for business logic; its purpose is to clearly separate logic from markup, whether this logic means processing some business objects or just deciding if something has to be rendered given the request's context.

**TL;DR:** No, you cannot pass arguments to included resources.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to do something similar is to "hack" the Sling selectors, it's not recommended but if you are calling a different renderer of the component based on parameters than Sling selectors maybe a good solution.....but I still feel it's a bit hacky